# Best way to examine longitudinal data?

Tags: normalization, standardization, pre-post-comparison

I had 20 patients come to clinic once a month for 6 months. At each visit we collected baseline data. We then gave the patients 3 different treatments to see the effects for each visit. Thus we have 18 different treatment responses recorded and 6 baseline recorded.

I want to calculate the change from baseline for each treatment at each visit. This is so I can then compare across time points as well.

For example: Session 1 - visit 1, session 2 - visit 1 etc.

What is the best way to analyze the data? change scores? normalization? standardization?

Comment: Why not just go with a linear model for starters? You can add a patient specific intercept, using e.g. lme4 in R.

Answer (score 2):

As demodw mentioned in the comments, a simple regression would be great start for inter-period comparisons. However, for longer term comparisons or across time comparisons (ie the final outcome), things may get more complicated, not least because there are only 20 patients to work with it. Beyond the simple regressions, [g-computations](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3105284/) and regressions on [longitudinal propensity scores](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2722117/) (RLPS) would be two more options you should consider. It would also be possible to go Bayesian on this (check out Gustafson (2015, Biometrics).

As a side note (I can't comment yet), there are elements of the question that could be clarified to help us answer your questions:

-Are the treatments that the patients receive symptom dependent, time dependent, both, neither?

-How were the treatments assigned? Is this a randomized controlled, blind experiment?

-Are there potential risks of non-adherence to treatment?